# Сортировка свойства массива по возрастанию

Tags: php

Есть массив `arRelated` у которого есть свойства `RELATED_SORT`, которое нужно отсортировать по возрастанию

```
   for($i=0; $i<(count($arRelated)-1); $i++){
        if(!empty($arRelated[$i]["RELATED_SORT"])){
            var_dump(sort($arRelated[$i]["RELATED_SORT"],SORT_STRING));    
        }
        var_dump($arRelated[$i]["RELATED_SORT"]);
    }
```

Печатаю `var_dump` выдаёт:

> bool(false) string(4) "1000" bool(false) string(3) "555" bool(false)
>   string(1) "5" bool(false) string(2) "10" bool(false) string(3) "200"

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Мне кажется вы что-то не то сортируете. У вас многомерный массив, и вам нужно отсортировать по вложенному ключу. А судя по коду, вы делаете не то. Ознакомьтесь вначале
https://intsystem.org/coding/sortirovka-mnogomernyh-massivov-po-klyuchu-na-php/

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($arRelated, function($a, $b){
    if ($a["RELATED_SORT"] == $b["RELATED_SORT"]) return 0;
    return ($a["RELATED_SORT"] < $b["RELATED_SORT"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[Сортировка с использованием пользовательской функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

Comment: @Naumov уважаемый, сказать "ваш код говно" и уйти с гордо поднятой головой - это как минимум не конструктивно и не вежливо. Если считаете себя вправе делать подобные заявления - потрудитесь их обосновывать, желательно не по принципу "мне так кажется", а приводя убедительные аргументы.

Comment: http://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/ 5.1. Конструкции if, elseif и else

Comment: @Naumov Начнем с того, что PSR является стандартом, которому должны следовать создатели фреймворков входящих в "PHP Framework Interop Group" и он ни коем образом не распространяется на всех разработчиков PHP. Мало того, многими он считается плохим и вредным для отрасли. Продолжим тем, что вы в своих ответах зачастую и сами его не соблюдаете(да, я пробежался и посмотрел).

Comment: Конкурсным ответом можно и принебречь... Просто это открытый ресурс, по которому многие учатся, и я в своей практике много увидел всяких нечитабельных приложений, не стоит довать почву ведь новичок будет брать как постулат писать `if(cond) result` и такие конструкции `cond?cond1:cond2?cond3:cond4` и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @Naumov следовать или не следовать какому либо(не общепризнанному!) стандарту - это ваше лично дело. Категорично навязывать свое личное мнение остальным - это уже что-то из серии "синдром вахтера". Код, приведенный мной - короткий и понятный. Мало того, вы умудрились придраться к куску из официальной документации.

Comment: @Naumov Два случайных ваших ответа. Не конкурсные. В обоих нарушение PSR-2. Глаз, бревно. Засим позвольте откланяться.

Comment: Красивый и простой код - это шедевр программирования - безмолвно защищающий своего автора.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь воспользоваться php функцией natsort. Она сортирует массив, используя алгоритм "natural order". 
То есть можно попробовать вот так

```
natsort($arRelated[$i]["RELATED_SORT"],SORT_STRING));
```